# Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `aws.connect.psdb.cloud`:`5432`

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, schema, prisma, vercel

Im trying to do a multi-tenant app guide on Vercel I followed all the steps till I got to the command `npx prisma db push` which keeps giving me this error.

I'm new to this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1E4s.png)

I tried looking for the server on AWS but to no luck

Comment: Are you able to connect to your database through psql or any other database IDE?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, In `.env` file. I removed the quotes for the Database URL and it is working now. Not sure if it was the thing which fixed it but that thing worked for me.

### **Potential Fix (which worked for me)**

Put the DB URL in the `.env` file and import it like this

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}
```

Inside `.env`

```
DATABASE_URL = url_with_quotes
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue and found the solution. You just have to add `?sslaccept=strict&connect_timeout=300` at the end of your connection string, located within your env file. Also, ensure that your connection string format is accurate.

Inside `.env`

```
DATABASE_URL = 'url + ?sslaccept=strict&connect_timeout=300'
```